# move a directory with a single character (back quote) as its name

Tags: directory, rename, filenames

How can I move a directory whose name is just a space?

```
ls -lah
drwx------  4 user1 user1 8.0K Mar 13 14:16 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  root    60 Mar 13 13:48 ..
drwx------ 18 user1 user1 4.0K Mar 13 11:18
```

It's the work of a virus, And I would like to undo it.

**Update:** I can't know for sure what is that character. As I try to move it like a space, and it doesn't work

```
$mv ' ' test
mv: cannot stat ` ': No such file or directory
```

**Update:** This is not a duplicate of [delete a file with no name](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28983/how-can-i-delete-a-file-with-no-name), although directory and file behave very similar in this case.

Comment: I created it and was able to move it with $mv ' ' test  Are you using Ubuntu? (I am).

Comment: I'm Fedora linux, but I don't think that's the issue. As I said, it's not actually a space. It's
` '

Comment: If it was a virus, don't rename the directory. [Nuke the whole installation from orbit](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32500/what-is-nuke-it-from-orbit) (i.e. do a full OS reinstall).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible approach is to find the inode number for the directory, and use that to `mv` it. You don't tell us what platform you are using, so you might need to modify these suggestions to fit the tools available to you (I'm on FreeBSD).

Use your `ls` utility to get the inode number - the `-i` switch does that on FreeBSD:

```
$ ls -i
106739 test
```

(`test` is an empty directory I just created to illustrate this solution)

Now, you can use the `find` utility to find the directory with the inode number:

```
$ find . -inum 106739
./test
```

And to move the troublesome directory:

```
$ find . -inum 106739 -exec mv {} fixed \;
find: ./test: No such file or directory
```

Don't worry about the error message - it happens because the directory index changes during execution of the command, so `find` gets a bit confused; the directory has been renamed to `fixed`:

```
$ find . -inum 106739
./fixed
```

As I said, you may need to consult your local documentation to get the right switches, but this approach should work.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for the hack.
I was possible by files explorer through graphical interface. I just wanted to do it in CLI

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
mv ' ' <where you want to move>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out what it is called, perhaps by something like

```
ls | od -c
```

Other thing to try is something like `mv ? somewhere` (if the name is one character), `mv ?? somewhere` (if it has two), ... The above `od(1)` command should tell the length, or from `ls -b` output.

If the name really is ' ' (one space), `mv ' ' somewhere` will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by running these commands:

```
$ mv " "  ..target..

$ ls -al
-rw-r--r--  1 yupadhya Domain Users..0 Mar 13.. 19:28
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 yupadhya Domain Users     0 Mar 13 19:28 .
drwxrwxrwt+ 1 yupadhya Domain Users     0 Mar 12 10:19 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 yupadhya Domain Users  1494 Mar 12 10:16 .bash_profile
-rwxr-xr-x  1 yupadhya Domain Users  6054 Mar 12 10:16 .bashrc

$ mv /home

$ ls -al
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 yupadhya Domain Users 0 Mar 13 19:28
drwxrwxrwt+ 1 yupadhya Domain Users 0 Mar 13 19:29 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 yupadhya Domain Users 0 Mar 12 13:14 ..

$ pwd
/home
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the dollar symbol to prevent the space character from being parsed, i.e

`mv $' ' /path/to/folder`

Otherwise it would not be treated as a parameter.