# How to remove failed file with backspace in its name?

Tags: filenames, rename, aix, special-characters

Sorry if I am not using the right terms for naming these "backspace chars".

I would like to clean up a directory that contains two files which looks like they contain backspace in their name. If I list the directory:

```
ls -la
```

I get this:

```
-rwxrwxrwx    1 guy guy        729 Jun 26 2007  z_regular.mk
-rwxrwxrwx    1 guy guy          1 Sep  7 2016
-rwxrwxrwx    1 guy guy       3220 Sep 27 2
```

I am thinking I mistakenly imputed the file names with "backspace chars", so we do not see the names any more.

## How do I rename these last two files?

I don't know how to call them. Is there an `ls` option allowing me to display the file names in hexa or something, and how could I use the latest in an `mv` command? I'm with AIX Unix TLS v6.

## edit:

the files are respectively 2 and 4 `del` chars:

```
ls -lb
```

gives

```
-rwxrwxrwx    1 guy guy          1 Sep  7 2016   \177\177
-rwxrwxrwx    1 guy guy       3220 Sep 27 2      \177\177\177\177\177
```

But solutions found at [How can I delete a file with no name](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28983/how-can-i-delete-a-file-with-no-name?rq=1) doesn't work for my case in AIX.

I tried the below without success so far:

```
l>ls -l $'\0177\0177'
$\0177\0177 not found
l>ls -l '\0177\0177'
\0177\0177 not found
l>ls -l '\177\177'
\177\177 not found
```

Answer (score 4):

The `$'\ooo'` syntax (from ksh93 and now found on most modern Bourne-like shells including `zsh`, `bash`, `mksh`, FreeBSD `sh`) uses the *standard* (as in C and most other languages) as opposed to `echo` syntax for octal escapes. So, that's `\` followed with up to 3 octal digits: `$'\177'`. `$'\0177'` would be like `$'\017'7`. So:

```
ls -ld $'\177\177'
mv $'\177\177' better-name
```

(note that `\177`, aka `^?` or `DEL` character in ASCII, is *not* the Backspace/`^H`/`BS`/`\10` character)

Answer (score 0):

I found solution at the bottom of suggested duplicate:

1. identify node numbers

   ```
   ls -lbi

   25553  -rwxrwxrwx    1 guy guy          1 Sep  7 2016   \177\177
   25559  -rwxrwxrwx    1 guy guy       3220 Sep 27 2      \177\177\177\177\177
   ```
2. then it's possible to move when returned from `find`:

   ```
   find . -inum 25553  |xargs -I{} mv {} recovered.x
   find . -inum 25559  |xargs -I{} mv {} recovered.y
   ```