# Delete file with broken name

Tags: linux, rm

I've somehow created a file that I can not seem to figure out how to delete via CLI.

```
$ ls -alF
total 8195
-rw-r--r--+ 1 me             my_group           0 Jul 19 14:10 ''$'\r'
drwxrwx---+ 1 system         system             0 Nov 17 14:58  ./
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 system         system             0 Jul 17 15:40  ../
...
```

The first line item here I can not seem to find the correct escape sequence to be able to delete.

Attempting to grep this entry does not even work properly:

```
$ ls -alF | head -n2
total 8195
-rw-r--r--+ 1 me             my_group           0 Jul 19 14:10
```

Note that when grepping / using other pipe'd commands, I can never see the name of the file.

*this is a Cygwin wrapped Win10 environment*

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/28983/117549

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1. Run `ls -li` to get the inode, then use `find` to delete it.

   ```
   ls -li foo
   42 -rw-r--r--. 1 user group 0 Nov 17 15:07 foo
   ```

If the inode was 42, as in the above example, run: `find . -inum 42 -exec rm -i {} \;`, which will interactively prompt you to remove the file.

2. Run `rm -i ? ?? ???` to have the shell expand to the one, two, and three-character filenames in the current directory; one of them will appear to be blank, and is probably the file in question; simply answer "no" to the prompts to remove the files you want to keep.

Comment: I've used linux for years.. Never knew you could print inode info with ls, and also did not know that bash expands `?`'s. Perfect answer, both solutions worked as expected.

Comment: the 1st one looks more reliable

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating a file with the same name as yours and I was able to delete it with rm every time. Do you know which version of rm you have installed? Perhaps the version you have is buggy? I assume you tried simply putting the name inside double quotes. If not, give that a try.

In the case that dosen't work, I'd suggest you try using rm with some wildcards. Move all other files out of the folder and just run the following.

`rm -f "*"`

That only failed me once, when the file filesystem itself was corrupt, and fsck didn't touch it. I honestly just left the file there until the next time I reformatted it.

Comment: Again, this is a Win10 env wrapped in Cygwin, so there could be differences there. `rm (GNU coreutils) 8.26 ||
Packaged by Cygwin (8.26-2)`

Comment: Interesting that Cygwin actually has a newer version of coreutils then I do. Have you tried deleting the file using only escape sequences? Like, rm $(echo -e "<escape sequences here>"). Perhaps specifying each character by code would work.